# How do I add canonical url to header in AW BLOG extension?

Tags: extensions, blog

Recently we saw many duplicate content hits in our blog and this is not good for SEO

This is due to using aw_blog not adding a canonical tag (actually there has not been any real development - other then urgent security fixes)

**Question:** How can we add a canonical tag to aw blog?

We were thinking of adding it to `_prepareMetaData` in Abstract.phtml

```
protected function _prepareMetaData($meta)
{
    if (is_object($meta)) {
        $head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        if ($head) {
            $head->setTitle($meta->getTitle());
            $head->setKeywords($meta->getMetaKeywords());
            $head->setDescription($meta->getMetaDescription());
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating the file `app/code/community/AW/Blog/Block/Abstract.php` (line 184)

with this code, seems to work

```
protected function _prepareMetaData($meta)
{
    if (is_object($meta)) {
        $head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        if ($head) {
            $head->setTitle($meta->getTitle());
            $head->setKeywords($meta->getMetaKeywords());
            $head->setDescription($meta->getMetaDescription());
            /** CUSTOM CODE SNH 10-jul-2015 **/
            if ($post_identifier = $identifier = $this->getRequest()->getParam('identifier')) {
                $url = $this->getBlogUrl($post_identifier);
                $url = rtrim(strtok($url, '?'),"/");
                $head->addLinkRel('canonical',$url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using getParam and not an object is not the nicest solution. Any other suggestions?

thx